# Regex : typed word matching beginning or whole word?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, forms

I'm actually working on a system that will suggest to a user, while he is filling a form input, a word he typed in this form field during a previous visit on the website (a Google-Like auto-complete form in fact).

My form is pretty basic : an input for firstname and another one for the lastname.

I'd like to know if there is a way, thanks to regex, to check if the typed word match the word I previously stored in LocalStorage.

**Example** :

The word I stored in localStorage is 'Matthew'.

The typed words that will match are : 'M', 'Ma', 'Mat', 'Matt', 'Matth', 'Matthe' and 'Matthew'.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: You cant query localStorage with regular expressions directly - you'll need to query the names out of localStorage in full and then perform the regexp match.

Comment: Your question is a little broad without the context of your code, but you can use the `^` character class to signify that the match should be made at the start of the string only. Therefore if the user had typed `Matt` your regex would be `/^Matt/i`

Comment: RegEx is to heavy a tool here. Use `indexOf` method of `String` prototype as Daniil Djidi states in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54667045/476951) below

Comment: Depends on how the words are "stored" - if it's a space separated string (ie `words += " " + newword)` then you'd need `/\bMa\S*\b/` - if it's stored as a list, then loop through the list checking `indexOf === 0`

Answer (score 0):

When I need to check regex expressions, I use this service: https://regex101.com/.

But for your task, I think you just need an indexOf() function:

```js
var userName = 'Matthew';
    
    var searchTerm = 'Ma';
    var indexOfFirst = userName.indexOf(searchTerm);
    
    console.log('The index of the first "' + searchTerm + '" from the beginning is ' + indexOfFirst);
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: This would match 'genoMa' too. What he is asking for is more like `/\bMa/` which is what Regular Expressions are made for...

Comment: Yes, you right Regular Expression it's best way to resolve it. But in that case you able to check if (indexOfFirst === 0) to get that we need.

Comment: In case you only want to predict whole sentences yes. But not if you want to predict words as you type. And, anyway, just inserting a trailing space at the beginning users can cheat you... Complex regular expressions may be heavy. But simple ones aren't as much weighty and, most importantly: It looks like you are trying to make a premature optimisation. Do you expect any user would notice a millisecond or even shorter delay in text prediction?

Answer (score 0):

In newer browsers there is a `string.startsWith(...)` function that will tell you if the string starts with an input

Refercence: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

If you need support for older browsers you can use the pollyfill from the above page:

```
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
    Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'startsWith', {
        value: function(search, pos) {
            pos = !pos || pos < 0 ? 0 : +pos;
            return this.substring(pos, pos + search.length) === search;
        }
    });
}
```